# Cómo importar módulos y clases?

Tags: python

Nuevamente me trabo en algo que no puedo explicar o encontrar la solución, pues en mi PC funciona bien, pero no en el servidor hosting. Mi código es así.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from Plantillas import ConformarPaginaHTML


from vista.Vistas  import Local #Esta línea es la problematica



sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))


def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
    plantilla = ConformarPaginaHTML('biblia')
    presentacionBiblia = plantilla.conformandoPagina()
    uriobtenida = environ['REQUEST_URI']
    if environ["PATH_INFO"]=="/":
        respuesta = "<p>Página inicial </p>"  + __file__ + "<br>" + os.path.dirname(__file__)
    elif environ["PATH_INFO"]=="/libros/genesis":
        respuesta = "<p>Bienvenidos a mi página web</p>"
    else:
        respuesta = "<p><trong>Página incorrecta </strong></p>"
    response = presentacionBiblia + uriobtenida 
    return [respuesta.encode()]
```

Cuando comento esta línea sale todo normal:

from vista.Vistas  import Local #Esta línea es la problematica

Este código está en el directorio principal, y "vista" es un subdirectorio del mismo, y Vista.py es un módulo que está en vistas que es el que deseo importar

La jerarquía queda más o menos así

```
-->pythonapp
     !
     ----  __init__.py
     ----  passenger_wsgi.py
     ----> vista
        !
        ----  __init__.py
        ---- Vista.py
```

En mi PC normal no aparece ningún error no sé si obligatoriamente tenga que recurrir a las funciones de `sys.path.`

Comment: Lo otro es que si un modulo que quiero importar está en el mismo paquete de mi modulo principal y lo importo entonces funciona bien. por ejemplo en el código esta línea no da problema: from Plantillas import ConformarPaginaHTML

Comment: Y el error que da es: We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

Comment: 'import os
Ya resolví el problema, era poner este código antes de importar los modulos

'path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0,path)'

Comment: No sé por qué debo hacer eso para desplegar la aplicacion en el servidor cuando cuando en mi pc solo basta con poner  `from vista.Vistas  import Local` y no da error

Comment: *mi pc solo basta con poner ...*, ¿lo has hecho de la CMD/Terminal o con una IDE? Seguramente lo has hecho con una IDE no has tenido problemas porque tu *solución* la implementa la IDE.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta eyllanesc, es verdad lo hice en mi pc desde Eclipse, ahora sin embargo si en el ide lo pongo como lo hice en el servidor hosting, entonces me señala que hay un error debo poner todo completo `from pythonapp.vistas.Plantillas import ConformarPaginaHTML` como pudiera hacer para que tanto el ide como el servidor hostinet estén en concordancia, pues como a penas estoy aprendiendo en lo del hosting, lo que hago es que cada vez que hago un cambio en el ide subo el archivo al servidor manualmente,

Comment: y entonces es un problema que aquí en el ide deba tenerlo de una forma y para subirlo al servidor tenga que cambiarlo a otra sintaxis, porque ahora es sólo un fichero pero te imaginas cuando comience a aumentar el proyecto??

Comment: No he usado hostinet pero en los servidores donde he desplegado aplicaciones hechas en python(Django principalmente) siempre añadia el path de mi proyecto a las configuraciones, en tu caso tu lo haces en el codigo.